# Triple boot laptop no longer boots after deleting partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, grub, lenovo-laptop

I am facing a problem on my Lenovo laptop Model No : G500.
When I press the power button, then the lenovo screen flashes and
the laptop further does not boot,the lenovo screen freezes.
It also does not go into the BIOS Settings.
I installed three OS's on my laptop which are Windows 7,Windows 8.1 and Fedora 20. I did Partitions of my hard disk for the three operating systems.I did Triple boot on my laptop and it was working fine,after that i tried to delete one partition then the above mentioned problem i faced.. I tried to delete one of my partition and again restarted then the above mentioned problem I faced.
It also did not go to the GRUB RESCUE MODE.
Please resolve my problem as early as possible

Comment: We're not here to "fix your problem ASAP"... we're here to offer possible solutions (from some of our own experiences) that you then decide the merit of the answers to try to give YOU the things to try and solve the problem. By deleting a partition you have obviously broken the boot data. Which partition did you delete? Which OS was on it (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't go into BIOS settings, my experience is that the system has more significant problems than just the data on the hard drive.  However, I think newer systems may have changed that behavior somewhat.

You need to boot the system.  If your hard drive's data (such as what's in the MBR/etc.), isn't letting you boot, then you need another boot media (CD, USB, floppy disk, PXE network, etc.)

One "short term" solution could be [GAG](http://gag.sf.net), which has the benefit of an easy deployment that doesn't require changing the hard drive.  That will probably be a relatively easy way to help you boot, if you're using MBR.  If you use GPT, that may affect which software will work well with your system.  (Searching for "Boot Manager" may be helpful, or possibly "Boot Loader" (but "Boot Manager" will probably give more useful results for a fast-easy fix).

Note that this answer is assuming that you've somehow wiped out some key boot data from an MBR (first boot sector), PBR (sector from the operating system's partition), or GPT-equivalent, and that the important data on the drive is still on the disk (including information about where the partitions are).  If not, you may have some more work needed.

If, even worse, you can't boot up with GAG, then you may need to make some adjustments, like changing the BIOS settings.  Yeah, I read that you don't seem to be able to do that, either.  But at least now you know that you're probably going to need to address this by focusing on something other than the data on your hard drive.  (Since you spoke about deleting a partition, the data on the hard drive seems like a logical spot to start.  However, we've now confirmed that there is no easy way to boot this system with the current setup, unless you can press some shortcut key that can help get you into BIOS setup somehow, possibly by going to the BIOS boot menu first, which might be a different shortcut key like F12.)  The good news is that your hard drive might be just fine, if the computer has some other issue that causes it to not boot.  Doing a hard drive transplant (moving this drive to another system, and optionally moving a working-and-bootable drive to this system) might be helpful.

Okay, let's look at a different possibility: maybe you can successfully boot with GAG.  Once you boot, you have options.  If you boot successfully and like GAG, then GAG will let you easily install itself to the hard drive, so you no longer need the CD/whatever.  Or, since you're booted into an OS, the OS will likely have some software that allows you to install a boot loader/manager.  The details will depend on which operating system you with to use.

If you need further help, please consider providing us more details, such as: What operating system did you delete?  How big is the hard drive (which is a good indicator of whether MBR-based software will work, or if you need GPT-based software)?  What do you see if you boot off of "bootable media" like a Linux-based live CD?  How did you try to get to GRUB rescue mode?  What buttons did you try pressing to get into BIOS setup?  Are there additional computers (of the same model) easily available?